# Datasource load entire data from db?

Tags: c#, .net, datasource, sql-server-ce

I have created datasource from northwind database (SQLCE).
Then i drag datasource item on form and grid was created.

Question is: Does datasource load all data from dataset? Or maybe it loads part of data when i scroll grid? How to ensure this?

Answer (score 0):

All data from the DB is fetched to the client.  To be sure that this is the case, just check the SelectCommand of the TableAdapter used to fetch data.

Also, I'm not sure about SQLCE, but MS SQL server allows you to track requests to the DB server using the SQL Server Profiler tool.